# Dynamically building queries

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dynamic

Hi and thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

After a year and a half of working with Java, I've decided to switch back to .NET. I must say that I feel at home in VS2012.

While working with Java I came across an implementation of hibernate that enabled for creating dynamic queries easily.

Imagine I had a form with 5 fields of which only one, any one, must be populated in order for me to filter the results by.

is there a way I can do the following in C#:

```
if(txtMunicipality.text.length > 0){
   (x => x.municipality == txtMunicipality.text)
}

if(chkboxIsFinished){
   (x => x.isfinished == true)
}
```

etc..

So I ccheck for every field and if the value has been populated then add that criteria to the query.. and after i'm done with the checks i execute the query. Is there a way to do this in C#?

Comment: May be: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: I think the question is not about Dynamic LINQ, but rather dynamically building the query.

Comment: yes you are right.. I will edit my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The simplest way is with **[delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**, especially the anonymous ones.

For example:

```
Func<YourEntity, bool> filter = (_ => true); // Default value.

if (txtMunicipality.text.length > 0)
{
    filter = (x => x.municipality == txtMunicipality.text);
}
else if (chkboxIsFinished)
{
    filter = (x => x.isfinished == true);
}
```

Then you can use the `filter` delegate in a query, for example in a `Where` statement (which I suppose was your intent - if not, the example is still relevant, just not directly applicable)

```
/ LINQ syntax.
var entities = from e in context
               where filter(e)
               select e;

// Method syntax.
var entities = context.Where(x => filter(x));
// Or simply:
var entities = context.Where(filter);
```

Comment: the `context.Where` version using a delegate would be ***really*** bad if that `context` is actually EF / L2S / NH etc; it will do the filtering at the .NET side rather than at the origin.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is to compose two queries, i.e.

```
IQueryable<Foo> query = ... // or possibly IEnumerable<Foo>
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMunicipality.text)) {
    query = query.Where(x => x.municipality == txtMunicipality.text);
}
if(chkboxIsFinished) {
    query = query.Where(x.isfinished);
}
```

You *can* also directly compose expression-trees and delegates; if you need that, please indicate which you have: an expression-tree vs a delegate.

---

Edit: here's how you would do that composing *expressions* rather than queries:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Expression<Func<int, bool>> exp1 = x => x > 4;
        Expression<Func<int, bool>> exp2 = x => x < 10;
        Expression<Func<int, bool>> exp3 = x => x == 36;

        var combined = (exp1.AndAlso(exp2)).OrElse(exp3);
        // ^^^ equiv to x => (x > 4 && x < 10) || x == 36
    }
    static Expression<Func<T, bool>> OrElse<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> x, Expression<Func<T, bool>> y)
    {   // trivial cases
        if (x == null) return y;
        if (y == null) return x;

        // rewrite using the parameter from x throughout
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.OrElse(
                x.Body,
                SwapVisitor.Replace(y.Body, y.Parameters[0], x.Parameters[0])
            ), x.Parameters);
    }
    static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AndAlso<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> x, Expression<Func<T, bool>> y)
    {   // trivial cases
        if (x == null) return y;
        if (y == null) return x;

        // rewrite using the parameter from x throughout
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.AndAlso(
                x.Body,
                SwapVisitor.Replace(y.Body, y.Parameters[0], x.Parameters[0])
            ), x.Parameters);
    }
    class SwapVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public static Expression Replace(Expression body, Expression from, Expression to)
        {
            return new SwapVisitor(from, to).Visit(body);
        }
        private readonly Expression from, to;
        private SwapVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
        {
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
        }
        public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
        {
            return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this article you can find some useful extension methods that allows you to combine predicates (it should work for NHibernate as well):

[LINQ to Entities: Combining Predicates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx)

You can then build a lambda expression like this:

```
Expression<Func<MyObject, bool>> predicate = x => true;

if(txtMunicipality.text.length > 0){
   predicate = predicate.And(x => x.municipality  == txtMunicipality.text);
}

if(chkboxIsFinished){
   predicate = predicate.And(x => x.isfinished == true);
}
```